# Accepted duplicate too quickly

Tags: support, status-completed

I asked the following question:

[Puppet.conf server specify port?](https://serverfault.com/questions/846290/puppet-conf-server-specify-port)

I assumed the answer and duplicate linked would solve my problem but after following both instructions, my problem still persists.

I realize it's my own fault for not confirming before accepting answer and duplicate. Is there anything I can do at this point?

Comment: You accepted an answer too, too fast, or it's really a correct answer ?

Comment: @yagmoth555 I still haven't fixed my issue which the question relates to. I both accepted the answer too fast & hit the 'this answers my question button' in regards to the possible duplicate. (answer on possible duplicate question didn't fix my issue either)

Comment: For the answer you can click to undo (you click the green checkmark), for the dupe question it will need a moderator intervention I think

Answer (score 2):

I had noticed your comment on the answer and got it re-opened before I even saw this! All set.